# How to manage multiple Connections to Zookeeper using Curator?

Tags: connection-pooling, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I am new to Zookeeper and Curator.

I want to know, If there is a way in Curator or Zookeeper through which we can maintain a Connection pool of zookeeper connections.

I tried searching the web but most of the people say one CuratorFramework/Zookeeper should be sufficient or try making connection again and again for using multiple connections parallely.

System I am designing, would require High no. of parallel reads/s from zookeeper. I am using Curator with single zookeeper connection. Multiple Zookeeper connection will allow reads to happen parallely instead of sequentially. Also, I want to reduce any delay caused by initiating a new connection again and again.

Ideally I am assuming that there should exist some Connection Pooling but if not I might need to do that by myself.

Can anyone point to something that already exists?

Comment: Why would you want to this? Can you provide an example? Connection pooling is provided out-of-the-box by ZooKeeper/Curator.

Comment: I might not know of intrinsic details on how zookeeper does connection management. But what i want to understand is if in a multi threaded application where a single ZK connection(Zookeeper object) is being shared by multiple threads, then if a get operation(or any other operation) is called by two threads for different paths, then whether those operations will be executed in parallel or sequentially by Zookeeper object on client side.

Comment: If Sequentially then what can be done to make it Parallel. Note: I do also want to reduce the overhead of making a connection again and again. Please recommend what should be done.

Comment: It's important to know that all writes in ZooKeeper go through the leader instance and are effectively sequential. ZooKeeper guarantees ordering of operations. The client itself use NIO internally so there is no blocking. I can't think of a reason to have more than one client in a JVM.